# Firefox Add-on SDK's selection module (sdk/selection) triggering more than once when going back and forward in webpages

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the Firefox Add-on SDK to create an add-on that triggers when the user selects text on a page. I use the high level module `sdk/selection` for this, but I found a problem.

This is a working test example, where my `main.js` is completely defined as follows:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var selection = require("sdk/selection");

var activeWorker = null;
var workerID = 0;

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("some-empty-file.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker)
    {
        worker.id = workerID++;

        worker.onSelection = function() {
            console.log("selected text: " + selection.text + " (from worker " + worker.id + ")");
        }

        worker.activate = function() {
            if (activeWorker != null) {
                activeWorker.deactivate();
            }
            console.log("activate worker " + worker.id);
            selection.on('select', worker.onSelection);
            activeWorker = worker;
        }

        worker.deactivate = function() {
            console.log("deactivate worker " + worker.id);
            selection.removeListener('select', worker.onSelection);
            activeWorker = null;
        }

        worker.on('pageshow', function() {
            console.log("pageshow " + worker.tab.title);
            worker.activate();
        });
    }
});
```

Essentially, it tries to attach a worker to a page everytime that page is shown, by disabling the active worker if it exists and then setting the new one. As you can see, every time I register a worker with the `selection.on('select', ...)` event, I do the respective `selection.removeListener('select', ...)` on the previous active worker. This should keep a single registration with the `selection` module at all times: the one made by the active worker.

But now please see the following `console.log`s, with associated steps:

Open `mozilla.org` and wait for page load.

```
log: pageshow Home of the Mozilla Project — Mozilla
log: activate worker 0
```

Select some text on the page (in this case, "volunteers"). It works fine.

```
log: selected text: volunteers (from worker 0)
```

Now open `mozilla.org/firefox` (on the same page).

```
log: pageshow Download Firefox — Free Web Browser — Mozilla
log: deactivate worker 0
log: activate worker 1
```

Select some text on the page (in this case, "Firefox"). It works fine.

```
log: selected text: Firefox (from worker 1)
```

Now press the back button to go to the last page.

```
log: pageshow Home of the Mozilla Project — Mozilla
log: deactivate worker 1
log: activate worker 0
```

We're back at Mozilla's main page. Select some text on the page again (in this case, "supporters").

```
log: selected text: supporters (from worker 0)
log: selected text: supporters (from worker 0)
```

It triggers twice.

I can't find a problem with my code, and the issue only appears when going back or forward in pages. If you keep opening pages and going back and forward in some ways, it'll start triggering more than twice.

Could this be a bug in the SDK or am I just doing something very wrong? Thanks!